# Not being able to get backspace character (\b) in the output on ubuntu (K&R example)

Tags: c, ubuntu, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* replacing tabs and backspaces with visible characters */
int main()
{
  int c;
  while ( (c = getchar() ) != EOF) {
       if ( c == '\t')
          printf("\\t");
       else if ( c == '\b')
          printf("\\b");
       else if ( c == '\\')
          printf("\\\\");
       else 
          putchar(c);
    }

   return 0;
  }
```

Now my question is .. Why can't I see "\b" in the output ? I have written this code in Ubuntu terminal. Is there any other way to get the "\b" character in output ? If there is , please explain in simple words as I have just started learning C programming.This example is from K&R exercise 1-10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the program and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

The key-code send by the [<kbd>backspace</kbd> key (also: <---)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace) is most probably eaten by the shell. This depends on how the terminal is configured. Read here for details: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html

Comment: so that means i need to press ctrl-h instead of backspace in the input itself ? Will the same program work fine in a windows pc ?

Comment: 1st question: yes/no, depending on how your terminal is setup (see the link in my answer); 2nd question: test it! ;-) (however, yes, it will under Cygwin using the default terminal setup)

Answer (score 2):

```
Is there any other way to get the "\b" character in output ?
```

If you are supplying the input like:

ab<kbd>backspace</kbd>cd

to your program then it'd result in `abc` because that is what the shell passed to the program.

Ensure that you send the correct input *to the program*.  Invoke it by saying:

```
printf $'ab\bcd' | /path/to/executable
```

and it'd print the expected output, i.e.:

```
ab\bcd
```

Comment: Hi, doesn't `abBACKSPACEcd` result in `acd`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid C code. It should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* replacing tabs and backspaces with visible characters */
int main()
{
  int c;
  while ( (c = getchar() ) != EOF) {
       if ( c == '\t')
          printf("\\t");
       else if ( c == '\b')
          printf("\\b");
       else if ( c == '\\')
          printf("\\\\");
       else 
          putchar(c);
   } // <-- note the closing curly brace
   return 0;
}
```

You should prepare a file containing the `\b` (`0x08`) and use it as input for your program. Another way would be to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Thanks @alk for the key combination)

Comment: Does this answer the question`?

Comment: Yes. If you craft a file containing backspace characters an use it as input, they will being replaced by `'\b'`. But you will need at least valid syntax.

Comment: thanks for the curly brace correction there..I will now check again